Function Key recognized by showkey and evtest command but not by xev on arch linux
I’m having an issue with one of the function keys on my Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 while running Arch Linux with KDE Plasma. The key in question (key code 364, which registers as KEY_FAVORITES) is working perfectly when I test it with showkey and evtest. I can see the correct key code when I press it.
However, when using xev, the key doesn’t produce any output at all.
Furthermore, when I look at the log of xorg I do see that my event input device is not considered as a keyboard. I see this kind of logs :
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i "keyboard"
...
[  1687.485] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[  1687.485] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[  1687.486] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
...

But not anything like that for the event 7 which is my event input that has the concerned key
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x19 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
Input device name: "Ideapad extra buttons"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    ...
    Event code 364 (KEY_FAVORITES)
...
Properties:

I don't understand what I need to add to make my input event device recognized as a keyboard.
If someone might be able to help me it would be very useful for a keyboard shortcut remapping. Thanks a lot!


X11 does not support keycodes above 247 (or 255, depending on context, due to a shift of 8 the kernel does for internal use), so it's expected to not show in xev.

The physical keyboard will show up as multiple separate devices in the keymap pipeline, so it's normal for some of the fn keys to not be handled by devices with "keyboard" in the name. It will still be working as an input device. So there might be nothing wrong.


Maybe that answers your questions already, but I'll take it a bit further.
Are you on Wayland? Use wev instead of xev.
Are you trying to map the key to a command? You may be able to map it already using the key symbol "XF86Favorites". (This is working for me right now, although I'm in River, not KDE Plasma.)
If that doesn't work I'd try evsieve, which seems to be a very powerful and simple tool that shortcuts past all the udev/hwdb/xkbkeymap complications. For example:
evsieve --input /dev/input/event7 --hook key:favorites exec-shell="echo 'Hello, World!'"

Not sure whether the X11 keycode limit could be a problem. If so, try setkeycodes (easier) or udev/hwdb mapping files (complicated/official/powerful) as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes. And then assign a key symbol to the keycode using xmodmap (X only) or xkbkeymaps (X and Wayland, complicated/official/powerful), or any number of other tools.
I'm also a relative novice struggling to map keys on my own Lenovo Slim 7 right now, so I'll say a bit more about it in comments.

• I found Fn+F4 (MicMute) and Fn+F8 (AirplaneMode) sending the same scancode, mapped to keycode KEY_UNKNOWN, but they first send "type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 13e" and "…13f". I couldn't find a way for udev/hwdb to map those, but evsieve works for now.
• The copilot key should send Super_L+Shift_L+F23, but F23 isn't being mapped. I couldn't get the device to accept a mapping to the F23 keycode at all, but it seems to work on the "Supported events" keycodes. I'll map to the Compose key to salvage it. Can't use it as a modifier unless evsieve can maybe capture/remap the whole macro

• F23 works fine after all. I forgot I was running interception-dual-function-keys, and it hooking Super_L was breaking the Copilot macro.
• Mapping the Fn key might be actually partially possible on this laptop due to Fn+some alphabet keys sending unique events. Very hacky to capture many of them, but feasible by turning on "Fool Proof Fn Ctrl" in BIOS and sieving by Ctrl firing 0–3 ms before alphabet keys.

Thanks you very much it worked for me. I was indeed trying to map my key to a command.
